# How does Chatterbot RT retweets without knowing?

Tags: chatbot, chatterbot

Im using the English trainer and i want the bot to answer my question with his best-match answer...

For some reason the bot answers with a retweet like so:
"RT KhaledAlwaleed THE BASIS OF ..."

I am using my own corpus dataset:

`bot = ChatBot("Bot")
bot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)
bot.train("chatterbot.corpus.bot")`

Where "chatterbot.corpus.bot" has only 5 questions and answers.
So sending him a long unrelated text to his dataset will confuse him but i was expecting an answer from the 5 answers available. How and why did he generate a RT retweet?!?!

How do i make him answer my provided answers only?

Thank you.

Comment: ChatterBot learns and updates its knowledge based on conversations that it has. I suspect it is responding with messages like these because it received them as a response from people it interacted with at some point. You can prevent the chat bot from learning by setting the `read_only` parameter like this: `ChatBot("Johnny Five", read_only=True)`.

Comment: But i specifically told my bot to train on my given "bot" dataset (bot.train("chatterbot.corpus.bot")) so how and why would he be able to answer something he doesn't know?

Comment: By default, the bot will learn new responses when someone talks to it. I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but I'm guessing that this tweet is an input that the bot received at some point.